MS Graph API - filter on nested variables while including manager
I am trying to pull in all employees from MS Graph. This request works great once I add the header value ConsistencyLevel to Eventual.
GET /v1.0/users/?$count=true&$filter=accountEnabled+eq+true+and+onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute3+eq+'Employee'

However, I also need to pull in the employeeId of their manager, but when I add that in, I get an error.
GET /v1.0/users/?$expand=manager($select=employeeId)&$count=true&$filter=accountEnabled+eq+true+and+onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute3+eq+'Employee'


Request_UnsupportedQuery Unsupported or invalid query filter clause
specified for property 'extensionAttribute3' of resource 'User'.

This is the same error that I would get on the original request prior to adding in the header value.
This request seems to work, but as this is for a university, it pulls in all students, which is a lot of records that I do not need.
GET /v1.0/users/?$expand=manager($select=employeeId)&$count=true&$filter=accountEnabled+eq+true


That's a limitation on the Graph API side, not all combinations of $expand and $filter are supported and this is one of them (filtering by onPremisesExtensionAttributes cannot be combined with expanding a manager)
The workaround seems to be to perform filtering by onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute3 on the client
Filter users only accountEnabled with expanded manager and return onPremisesExtensionAttributes to the client. Then apply filtering on the client side
GET /v1.0/users?$expand=manager($select=employeeId)&$count=true&$filter=accountEnabled+eq+true&$select=id,userPrincipalName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes

